# java - wicket - drag and drop (wicket-dnd)

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, wicket

I would like to use drag and drop functions in my wicket application.
Into my pom.xml I add: wicket-dnd (http://code.google.com/p/wicket-dnd/)

But my code do not work. Could you help me, please?

I have got table. In the first cell ("td") is "span" element. I want this "span" drag and drop into another cell ("td") in the table.
Thanks for help.

```
        WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer("container");
    Model<String> model = Model.of(new String("AAA"));
    container.add(new DragSource(Operation.values()) {
          public void onAfterDrop(AjaxRequestTarget target, Transfer transfer) {

              System.out.println("AAAAA");

          }
        }.drag("span"));

    container.add(new DropTarget(Operation.values()) {
          public void onDrop(AjaxRequestTarget target, Transfer transfer, Location location) {
            // add transfer data

              System.out.println("rrrr");
          }
        }.dropCenter("td"));

    Label label = new Label("aaa", model);
    label.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    container.add(label);

    add(container);
```

and HTML:

```
    <div wicket:id="container" class="container">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><span wicket:id="aaa" class="aaa">www</span></td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your s have to output their markup id, otherwise wicket-dnd will not be able to notify the server which drop location was chosen by the drop operation.